# Recommended file system for cloning AUR-mirror?

Tags: arch-linux, filesystems, git

I'm beginning to use Arch Linux and wanted to explore the AUR repository. Because of this motivation, I learned two things immediately.

- Ext3 can support only 32000 sub-directories. (I ran into cannot create dir error.)
- Ext4 can support up to 64000 sub-directories.

However, after clone the project in tmpfs, I learned there are over **65000** directories in the project! Thus, *even with ext4, it will not be able to handle this properly.*

What are people's choice when coming to selecting file systems for managing AUR-mirror (with large amount of sub-directories)?

Comment: Can you provide a reference for the EXT4 limit of 64k directories? A short test with `mkdir {1..70000}` seems to work.

Comment: Why exactly do you wish to keep an AUR mirror with you locally? The AUR is extremely large, and it is highly unlikely that you will use even 1% of the packages listed on it. I'm assuming that you have some misunderstanding of what the AUR is and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing the ports system. You don't want to clone the entire AUR
repo Im sure. So if your question is which file system I use ext4. Some like btrfs. There are others for encryption but stick with one of those for now.